# merge Dataframes pandas so that each date in the left Dataframe is assigned a value from the right Dataframe

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two DF:

1. holidays_df - contains information about dates and whether these dates are days off
2. df_sales - contains information about sales for every day in each stores

I want to put every day in df_sales information on whether or not a day off

holidays_df:

| date | day_off |
| --- | --- |
| 2017.12.01 | True |
| 2017.12.02 | False |
| .......... | ..... |
| 2017.12.31 | False |

df.sales:

| date | Sales | Stores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017.12.01 | 10 | 1 |
| 2017.12.01 | 20 | 1 |
| 2017.12.01 | 0 | 2 |
| 2017.12.02 | 15 | 1 |
| 2017.12.02 | 45 | 5 |
| .... | ..... | ...... |
| 2017.12.31 | 10 | 6 |

result could be like this

result_df:

| date | Sales | Stores | day_off |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017.12.01 | 10 | 1 | True |
| 2017.12.01 | 20 | 1 | True |
| 2017.12.01 | 0 | 2 | True |
| 2017.12.02 | 15 | 1 | False |
| 2017.12.02 | 45 | 5 | False |
| .... | ..... | ...... | ....... |
| 2017.12.31 | 10 | 6 | False |

I have tried to merge them with df_sales.merge(holydays_df, on='date', how= 'left'), but in result_df I have 800 rows less than in the original df_sales!

how to merge df_sales and holydays_df? I need the same number of rows in df_sales and result_df

Comment: I have to describe shapes of dataframes: df_sales (3000888, 9) , holiday_df = (139, 2), so I need the same number of rows in result: 3000888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `pd.Series.map`:

```
df_sales['day_off'] = df_sale['date'].map(holidays_df.set_index('date')['day_off'])
```

Comment: No, I got an InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

Comment: I have to describe shapes of dataframes:  df_sales (3000888, 9) , holiday_df = (139, 2)

Comment: Seems like holidays_df has duplicate rows for date... You could `holidays_df.drop_duplicates('date').set_index('date')['day_off']' to ensure you have a single row in the your dataframe for each date.

Comment: Meh.. its true, holidays has duplicate rows. first off all I have to deal with it

Comment: Scott, its great, thanks a lot) its working)

Answer (score 0):

Use `outer` instead of `left`. This should keep all rows and will fill them with NaNs:

```
df_sales.merge(holidays_df, on='date', how='outer')
```

Comment: I tried this. but i have extra 7132 rows - result_df.shape (3008020, 10), I need 3000888